How to correctly update PivotTable filters in OpenXML without breaking the PivotTable?
I'm working on an Excel document using OpenXML, and I need to programmatically update the filters of a PivotTable. Specifically, I want to change the filter applied to a field (e.g., "Gender") to display "F" (Female) and hide "M" (Male).
Below is the code I am using, where I try to manipulate the SharedItems of the CacheField corresponding to the "Gender" field:
[HttpPost("update-filter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePivotFilter()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(_filePath))
        return NotFound($"File not found: {_filePath}");

    try
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(_filePath, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "PivotTableSheet");

            if (sheet == null)
                return BadRequest("Sheet not found.");

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
            PivotTablePart pivotTablePart = worksheetPart.PivotTableParts.FirstOrDefault();

            if (pivotTablePart == null)
                return BadRequest("No PivotTable found in the sheet.");

            PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart pivotCacheDefinitionPart = pivotTablePart.PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart;
            var cacheFields = pivotCacheDefinitionPart.PivotCacheDefinition.CacheFields.Elements<CacheField>();

            CacheField genderField = cacheFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Gender");

            if (genderField == null)
                return BadRequest("Field 'Gender' not found in the PivotTable.");

            var sharedItems = genderField.SharedItems;

            // Attempt to filter out "M" and keep "F"
            for (int i = 0; i < sharedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = sharedItems.ElementAt(i);

                if (item.InnerText == "F") 
                {

                    //item.Val
                }
                else if (item.OuterXml.Contains("M"))
                {
                    // Hide 'M'
                    item.Remove();
                    sharedItems.Count--;
                    i--;
                }
            }

            pivotCacheDefinitionPart.PivotCacheDefinition.Save();
        }

        return Ok("PivotTable filter updated.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, $"Error updating the filter: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

Problem:
When I remove the element corresponding to "M" from the SharedItems, the entire PivotTable disappears and leaves only static values (numbers) in place of the original PivotTable structure. This happens after removing the first element from SharedItems.
I am using Remove() because I can't find any alternative method or attribute similar to "Hide" that would allow me to hide the "M" values without removing them completely. I am able to access the filters and inspect the field values, but the moment I try to remove or modify any element from SharedItems, the PivotTable structure breaks.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
